# Creating square of exact size (e.g. 1 km²) around point in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, geometry

I struggle to create a geometry with the exact size of a square with for example 1km² around a specific GPS point, to later export an image.

Is there a way to define the length of each side of the square and center it around a given location?

Or if not, can I calculate the corners of the square by using my GPS data and create the square like this?

```
// Create a geodesic polygon
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon
([ [[-105.35, 39.95], [-105.35, 40.05],[-105.2, 40.05], [-105.2, 39.95], [-105.2, 39.95]] ]);

// Display the polygon on the map
Map.centerObject(geometry);
Map.addLayer(geometry, {color: 'FF0000'}, 'geodesic polygon');

// Print polygon area in square kilometers.
print('Polygon area: ', geometry.area().divide(1000 * 1000));
```

This is what I can do. Basically just creating an Polygon without the same edge lengths (not a square) and measuring the size of it in km². But I am not able to define the exact size of it and to center it over a specific point (sampling site).

Comment: What have you tried (show your code) and what error/problem did you encounter with it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get an approximate solution, you can just buffer your point and take the bounds of the result.

```
var square = point.buffer(ee.Number(areaM2).sqrt().divide(2), 1).bounds()
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/44050171abbb0a68d50cbd35e6da6dff

I don't know any good way of getting an exact answer, but I suppose you could iterate the buffering solution with different values until you converge to a solution. It's probably a bad idea to do in practice though, but it works.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/3dc6ac4e72eb0456745c85698e91cc7e

Comment: Amazing! A cup of coffee on my name please!